# Tempo Real em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, real-time

Sou iniciante (nem tanto) na área da programação, e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

No site [globoesporte.com](http://globoesporte.com), especificamente nas páginas de transmissão em tempo real dos jogos, ao abrir o *Console*, percebi que o conteúdo da página (os lances da partida) era atualizado mesmo sem qualquer tipo de requisição (pelo menos visível no console) do tipo *XHR* ou *Fetch*.

Como isso é possível?

Comment: WebSockets é uma das possibilidades

Comment: Em complemento da resposta do Rodrigo: Para JavaScript, você pode utilizar https://socket.io

Answer (score -3):

Isso é possível gracas *Sockets TCP*.

Uma conexão *http* normal cria uma única via de comunicação com o servidor.
Ou seja o cliente tem que ficar fazendo requisições ao servidor, para receber suas respostas. No caso de um ambiente *realtime*, isso seria muito pesado, ou seja o cliente ficaria o tempo todo fazendo perguntas ao server, para verificar se existe atualização.

Quando se cria uma conexão *Socket TCP*, passamos a ter duas vias de comunicação, ou seja alem do cliente conhecer o servidor, o servidor conhece o cliente, e consegue mandar mensagens para o cliente.

O que você percebeu no site do globoesporte.com, é exatamente uma conexão criada por um socket, basicamente o que acontece é o seguinte.

Quando você entra no site para acompanhar o jogo realtime, o browser faz uma pedido ao server para estabelecer uma conexão socket, assim criando um *hub*, graças a isso, o seu browser não precisa de ficar fazendo requisições a cada segundo para verificar se existe alguma atualização para te mostrar, mas o servidor que irá enviar uma mensagem para o seu browser.

Não sei qual a linguagem server que você utiliza, mas eu uso C#, que tem como uma ótima solução de socket, o SignalR, [Aqui está um tutorial microsoft sobre SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

Sei que Java também tem uma solução socket, mas desconheço seu nome.